# log4j2 version in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: tomcat, log4j2

I am trying to check log4j2 version in ubuntu 20.04.
I am getting the output as below. Can somebody explain what is the actual version of log4J2?

### Command used: sudo apt list -a liblog4j2-java

liblog4j2-java/focal-updates,focal-security 2.17.1-0.20.04.1 all

liblog4j2-java/focal 2.11.2-1 all

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"

### Tomcat version

Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.73
Server built:   Nov 11 2021 13:14:36 UTC
Server number:  8.5.73.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     5.15.0-1031-azure
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    11.0.18+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04.1
JVM Vendor:     Ubuntu

I am unable to decide which is the actual version of log4j2.
If the version is 2.11.2-1 all, then do I need to update it as there is vulnerability in log4j2?
Thank you.

Comment: What does `apt policy liblog4j2-java` say?

Comment: liblog4j2-java: 
  Installed: (none) 
  Candidate: 2.17.1-0.20.04.1 
  Version table: 
     2.17.1-0.20.04.1 500
        500 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages 
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
     2.11.2-1 500 
        500 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages

Comment: As you can see, no `liblog4j2-java` package is installed. Remark however that only Java applications packaged by Debian/Ubuntu use the `liblog4j2-java` package, most Java applications just include the JARs in their distribution.

Comment: So, do I need to install log4j2 for my server?
Will it cause any error as such?

Comment: No, you don't need the `liblog4j2-java` package. If `liblog4j2-java` is not installed it means that no Java application **packaged** by Debian requires it. External applications will use their own version anyway.